# How i can remove point from number using loop function

Tags: php, html

I have this codes. My question is How i can remove .1 one from rest of numbers in my output.

Its gives : The counter is 1464.1
I want it to give : The counter is 1464

```
<?php
$i = 1000;
$t = 10;
while ($i < 100000000) {
echo"<p>The counter is $i";
$i = $i + ($i / $t);
}
?>
```

And output is :

> The counter is 1000
>
> The counter is 1100
>
> The counter is 1210
>
> The counter is 1331
>
> The counter is 1464.1
>
> The counter is 1610.51

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) This is not complicated. A simple cast or a regex replacement will work.

Comment: 0_0 Who up-voted this question?!  Seriously, the OP showed absolutely no effort or initiative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
echo '<p>The counter is '.intval($i) .'</p>';
```

EDIT:

Display purposes only use the above code.

Data manipulation use:

```
$i = intval ($i + ($i / $t));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$i = intval( $i + ($i / $t) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type cast it when you echo it.

```
echo "<p>The counter is " . (int)$i . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo "<p>The counter is ".floor($i)."</p>";
```

or

```
echo "<p>The counter is ".intval($i)."</p>";
```

These will effectively 'cut off' the decimal (or give you the integer value)

or you can round to the nearest integer:

```
echo "<p>The counter is " . round($i) . "</p>";
```

OR if you are trying to subtract .1 from your answer (it is unclear in the OP without more examples) you can do this:

```
echo "<p>The counter is ".($i - .1)."</p>";
```